# How do I install VirtualBox on Windows 7 64-bit? It says the MSI installation fails

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

Has anyone managed to install VirtualBox on Windows 7 64-bit ? While VirtualBox installs on Windows 7 32-bit, the installer eventually fails under Windows 7 64-bit - are there any tricks I need to be aware of?

I'm already running the installer as Administrator.

The installer stops at this point for about 3-4 minutes:

[image]

And eventually fails with:

[image]

Comment: Where in the installation does it fail?  After or before the networking/USB driver installation?

Comment: **If you have a similar issue and this doesn't answer you, please [ask a new question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) about it.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latest version of Virtualbox, 3.0.6, is said to work on 64bit.
Generally, error 1603 involves account permissions on the target system, free disk space on the target system, or bad file download or locked/inaccessable file.

So question: While running the installer, did you do "Run as administrator"?

Note: Check the BIOS to ensure that your CPU supports VT-x and that it is enabled.

Comment: For VirtualBox you don't require VT-x even to run the 64-Bit hosts. It is only required for 64-Bit guests. However it is a permissions issue, since I have run VirtualBox since before v3 on 64-Bit 7. It may also be a corrupt installation file.

Comment: Agreed, VT-x is not mandatory. It's only that I've seen comments recommending it whatever is the host/guest.

Comment: it installs after I enabled vt-x

Comment: Interesting. I have a machine without VTX and have been running it fine. Might need to open a ticket with Sun for them to investigate.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, but the second image doesn't shows, only the first one. I have a HP Pavillion dv9830us notebook, and I don't have a VT-x option in my BIOS. Is it locked? Are there other alternatives besides activating VT-x? I tried a lot of Virtualbox installers, even the last one (3.2.4)

Comment: You might try seeing if there's a BIOS update for your motherboard, taking extreme care not to brick the computer. Also a shorter moniker may help in getting forum messages.

Comment: I don't want to risk a BIOS update, if this machine brick I'm going to have a lot of problems. It's amazing WHY THE HELL hp locker my BIOS. This is ridiculous. And more amazing is virtualbox setup verifying VT-x in it's installation file even if you're not ever going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I received weird error messages (like Files corrupted) also while installing Windows in VirtualBox.

If things are going really weird, lack of disk space is often the problem like harrymc already mentioned and in my case, that was exactly the problem.

I've moved my images onto another partition that had plenty of space and Windows just installed fine.